# What is the expected fraction of observations in the top x% that remains in the top x% after a random shock?

Tags: probability, density-function, ranking

I'm struggling with a probability question, and I was hoping someone here could help me out. Here's the setting. Suppose you draw observations from a probability distribution Z and sort these observations from largest to smallest. Then, you add a random shock to the value of each observation and sort them again from largest to smallest. The random shock comes from probability distribution W. I want to know what's the expected fraction of observations in the top x% of the original ordering that remain in the top x% after the random shock. I want to express the solution in terms of x and the pdf of W and Z.

How would you do this?

Thanks in advance for any help you may provide me!